# How can I print one question per page in exams2pdf?

Tags: r-exams

I am writing an exam using exams2pdf. Is there a way to get each question on a new page?

I did not find an option in the manual so far.

Comment: add blank lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in this thread in the R-Forge forum: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/message.php?msg_id=48478&group_id=1337

Just redefine the `{question}` environment in the LaTeX template file:

```
\renewenvironment{question}{\item}{\newpage}
```

This adds a `\newpage` at the end of the question so that the next one starts on a new page. See `vignette("exams", package = "exams")` for more details about how to set up a LaTeX template file.

Comment: Thanks for posting the question plus answer - it's good to have this searchable on StackOverflow as well :-) I've added a few more details and a bit of formatting. It would be great if you accept your own answer (by clicking the check mark on the left of the question), once you are allowed to do so. If I recall correctly you have to wait for a few days whether there are any other answers.